# Advice on how to work on a old rails 2.x with ruby 1.8.7 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have inherited a very old rails 2.x application that uses ruby 1.8.7.

I want to upgrade this thing but I can't even get it installed on my laptop because of Ruby 1.8.7.

What is the best way for me to run this application locally to start the eventual upgrade process?

Can I go from Rails 2.x to Rails 5.x or that is not advisable?

Comment: What problem/error do you face while installing Ruby 1.8.7?

Comment: And no, going directly to 5.x won't show warnings of previous versions deprecated code, so it could become a nightmare.

Comment: I suggest using [rvm](https://rvm.io/) to manage ruby versions. Migrating from Rails 2.x is a major undertaking and is fraught with difficulties. You will need to migrate in stages 2 to 3 to 4 to 5 to reduce the risk of problems. The changes between Rails 2 & 3 were significant. Test & version control will be your best friends. It may be an easier route to rewrite the application from scratch.

Comment: Rails deprecates things on the next version and then on the version after that it is removed. So, for example, Rails' 2 `some_method` would be deprecated in Rails 3 (but still usable) but then in Rails 4 `some_method` would be removed. So no, you can't easily do the jump Rails 2 => Rails 5. Also, as I worked on applications with Rails 2.x, I remember that `bundler` needed to be downgraded to make Ruby 1.8.7 work. And maybe RVM also needs to be downgraded for that. Try to show us what error message you get when you do `rvm install ruby-1.8.7`

Answer (score 0):

That is a super loaded question, with a whole bunch of variables to what is the right answer.  Going to assume from the fact that it is still on Rails 2.X and Ruby 1.8.7 that there are no tests or such for you to confidently step through upgrading in the traditional route.

You can not do the jump from 2 => 5 in one go. The jump from 2 => 3 is big no matter the size of the application, there are just far to many internal API changes.  The move from 3 => 5 is not that bad if you can make it through the 2 => 3 upgrade you can likely skip 4 and move from 3 => 5.

I have no idea your experience level but will assume it intermediate at best with the nature of your questions. I would do some digging into Rack and web server proxies and maybe take an approach of rewriting portions of the application at a time. The underlying structure of data has changed very little although the code has. If it is at all modual or RESTful you could mount/proxy to different portions of the application to different versions of Rails in combination with [RVM](https://rvm.io/) or [RBev](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv)

Comment: I'm scared of the view layer changes.  Can I just skip using the asset pipeline and keep my js files in the public folder? (at least till the last step)